# How to recompile the Python 2.5 bytecode to 2.7?

Tags: python, bytecode

How can I recompile some .pyc files made by Python 2.5 with Python 2.7?

I do not have the source files and I cannot obtain it.

I am looking for a free solution.

Comment: Why? isn't 2.5's bytecode compatible with 2.7?

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it. The exact bytecode format is generally an implementation detail and not expected to be portable.

Comment: +1; I don't know if this is a good idea, but it is an interesting question.

Comment: @DanD. Python bytecode isn't portable across versions, and attempting to import modules built with a different python version won't work. To sorin: this may not work for you (after some searching), but you could attempt to decompile the pyc files back to source, and then compiling them with python 2.7: http://depython.net/ and http://www.crazy-compilers.com/decompyle/ are online decompile services for python, but they are not free.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211/free-python-decompiler-that-is-not-an-online-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need Python 2.5 and 2.7 and byteplay (http://code.google.com/p/byteplay/) installed to both.

diz.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import byteplay, marshal, sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdin.read(8)
    c = byteplay.Code.from_code(marshal.load(sys.stdin)).code
    labels = set([ x for l in c for x in l if isinstance(x, byteplay.Label) ])
    labels = dict([(l,i) for (i,l) in enumerate(labels)])
    byteplay.Label.__repr__ = lambda self: "labels[%d]" % labels[self]
    print repr(c)
```

az.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import byteplay, sys, imp, struct, marshal, time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    byteplay.labels = dict([(i, byteplay.Label()) for i in xrange(10000)])
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        import os, msvcrt
        msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    asm = sys.stdin.read()
    c = eval(asm, byteplay.__dict__)
    c = byteplay.Code(c, (), (), 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '').to_code()
    sys.stdout.write(imp.get_magic())
    sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('<L', time.time()))
    marshal.dump(c, sys.stdout)
```

usage:

```
python2.5 diz.py < foo.pyc > foo.az
python2.7 az.py < foo.az > foo.2.7.pyc
```

Comment: Of course because of api differences the module may raise exceptions when run on 2.7 but then you can always go and hack the assembly produced by diz.py